# Extjs 4.2: How to set the value of grid

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid for terminals, What I want to do now is to display the selected terminals into another grid. I am able to get the selected terminals with this code:

```
var sel = scope.getTerminalGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var user = scope.getProfinfo().getForm().getValues();

for(var i=0; i < sel.length; i++)
{
var terminals = sel[i].data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the data (in your case above its the 'sel' variable) and then load it in the second grid store.

Something like that:

```
var sel = scope.getTerminalGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var selRecords = sel.getSelection();
var secondGrid = scope.getMySecondGrid();
var secondStore = secondGrid.getStore();

secondGrid.removeAll(); //Clear the data
secondGrid.add(selRecords);
```

Of course, I separated all in a lot of variables, you can abstract some of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it multiple ways, one is with a drag and drop grid group, another is grabbing the grid of second store like so .

```
   var secondGrid = scope.getMySecondGrid()
   secondGrid.getStore()
```

the store is the powerful underlying data structure of the grid. You can then load any data you want in there.